# How can I display grid menu items on click on hamburger menu button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a menu done with grid, it is divided into 3 columns. In first I have my logo, in second I have menu items and last is a place for button. I have media query to hide menu items and display hamburger icon. The question is, how can I make menu items to drop below on icon click?

Here is the code:

```js
let menus = document.getElementsByClassName('hammburger-menu');

[].forEach.call(menus, function(m) {
    m.addEventListener('click', function() {
        m.classList.toggle('open');
    })
});
```

```css
body .navbar {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: 50px;
      grid-template-rows: 50px;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

body .navbar .brand {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: end;
}

body .navbar .hammburger-menu {
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 0;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 890px) {
  body .navbar .hammburger-menu {
    display: inline;
  }
}

body .navbar .hammburger-menu div {
  background-color: #fea100;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

body .navbar .hammburger-menu.open .one {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(9px) rotate(45deg);
}

body .navbar .hammburger-menu.open .two {
  opacity: 0;
}

body .navbar .hammburger-menu.open .three {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(-45deg);
}

body .navbar .navbar-nav {
  text-align: center;
}

body .navbar .navbar-nav input {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
}

body .navbar .navbar-nav a {
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-family: "Sintony";
  font-weight: 700;
  size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 890px) {
  body .navbar .navbar-nav a {
    display: none;
  }
}

body .navbar .button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 47px;
  background-color: #fea100;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}

body .navbar .button a {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 26%;
}

body .navbar .button img {
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
        <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt=""></a>
        <div class="navbar-nav slider-down">
            <div for="nav-toggle" class="hammburger-menu">
                <div class="one"></div>
                <div class="two"></div>
                <div class="three"></div>
            </div>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Reservation</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Recipe</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pages</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <a href=""><img src="images/icon_plate_navbar_button.png">BOOK YOUR TABLE</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, group the links in one `div`

```
<div class="hammburger-links">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Home</a>
    ...
    <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

And then, when you apply `display: none`, none of it will exists on the page. So instead, we apply `visibility: hidden` to make it possible to reappear.

```
@media (max-width: 890px) {
  .navbar-nav .hammburger-links {
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
  }

  .navbar-nav .hammburger-links a
  {
    display: block; /* make the links block element */
    border: 1px solid black;
  }

  .navbar-nav.open .hammburger-links
  {
    visibility: visible; /* when the nav is opened, we make the links visible */
  }
}
```

Finally, instead of applying `.open` to the hamburger, we apply it to `.navbar-nav`

```
[].forEach.call(menus, function(m) {
  m.addEventListener('click', function() {
    m.parentElement.classList.toggle('open');
  });
});
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/re9nu31k/

P.S. The styling is your job ;) 
P.S.2 I don't think you need to include body in every css selector

Comment: Also, I don't get why you're iterating through all the menus. Are you having many hamburger menus? If yes, that's gonna give you some pain.

Comment: Im using sass so I group everything in body, sholdn't I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the css you mention display: none that's why it is not display

```
@media (max-width: 890px)
body .navbar .navbar-nav a {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure if you get what im asking for, i want to hide menu items displayed horizontal and display them using button vertically

Answer (score -1):

i didn't touch your code has already created just added some stuff :

HTML :

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50

C/O https://placeholder.com/" alt=""></a>
        <div class="navbar-nav slider-down">
            <div for="nav-toggle" class="hammburger-menu">
                <div class="one item" style="display: none;"></div>
                <div class="two item" style="display: none;"></div>
                <div class="three item" style="display: none;"></div>
            </div>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link " href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Reservation</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Recipe</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pages</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/icon_plate_navbar_button.png">BOOK YOUR TABLE</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS :

```
body .navbar {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: 50px;
      grid-template-rows: 50px;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

body .navbar .brand {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: end;
}

body .navbar .hammburger-menu {
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 0;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 890px) {
  body .navbar .hammburger-menu {
    display: inline;
  }
}

body .navbar .hammburger-menu div {
  background-color: #fea100;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

body .navbar .hammburger-menu.open .one {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(9px) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(9px) rotate(45deg);
}

body .navbar .hammburger-menu.open .two {
  opacity: 0;
}

body .navbar .hammburger-menu.open .three {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(-9px) rotate(-45deg);
}

body .navbar .navbar-nav {
  text-align: center;
}

body .navbar .navbar-nav input {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
}

body .navbar .navbar-nav a {
  color: #000000 !important;
  font-family: "Sintony";
  font-weight: 700;
  size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 890px) {
  body .navbar .navbar-nav a {
    display: none;
  }
}

body .navbar .button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 47px;
  background-color: #fea100;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}

body .navbar .button a {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 26%;
}

body .navbar .button img {
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.open {
  display: block !important;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.hammburger-menu .item ');
const btn = document.querySelector('.button');

console.log(menus)
menus.forEach(function(elem) {
console.log(elem);
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        elem.classList.toggle('open');
    })
});
```

It's better like that

Comment: What does it change ?